# qplaintextedit line spacing

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to edit the spacing/margin between each line in a qplaintextedit?

I have tried editing the stylesheet using normal html/css tags (line-height), but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A co-worker of mine tried to solve a similar problem a few days ago with Qt 4.7.4. What he found is that we could set line spacing with class [QTextBlockFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextblockformat.html):

> Line spacing is set with setLineHeight() and retrieved via
>   lineHeight() and lineHeightType(). The types of line spacing available
>   are in the LineHeightTypes enum.

Unfortunately this functionality was introduced in Qt 4.8.

So you can set line spacing if it is possible for you to use Qt 4.8, QTextBlockFormat, QTextDocument and QTextEdit instead of QPlainTextEdit.

Comment: Ah, I'm using 4.7.3. But this help a lot.Thanks! :)